# How do I find out from where a registration in the DryIoC container was invoked?

Tags: asp.net-core, dryioc, .net-8.0

I'm using DryIoC in (combination with ASP.NET Core) and am getting a DryIoc.ContainerException seemingly because of a wrong registration.

> Registering implementation type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleFormatterConfigureOptions is not assignable to service type Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.JsonConsoleFormatterOptions>.'

I created a DryIoC container and using it in the WebBuilder:

```
WebApplicationBuilder? builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(
    new DryIocServiceProviderFactory(DiContainer));
```

How can I find out, where this registration is done?

Or someone can directly tell me what to do to get rid of the error...

**Update:**

I found that the registration comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions. But still do not know why.

Here is the example code if you start with a new asp.net core project:

```
using DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var container = new DryIoc.Container();

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );
            builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory( new DryIocServiceProviderFactory( container ) );

            var app = builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

builder.Build() raises the exception.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere (like github)?

Comment: I found that it comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Example: https://github.com/MathiasRotter/DryIoCIssue.git

Comment: Does not reproduce the issue for me (after fixing packages versions - it seems that you are using [central package management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) which was not added to the repo).

Comment: Sorry for that. But you brought me to the right track. THANK YOU!
I was using older versions because we have our own proget server. 
Updating to the latest release versions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by using older versions of `DryIoc.dll` (4.0.5) and `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` (3.0.3) with .NET 8.

After upgrading to latest stable versions the issue is gone.

Many thanks to Guru Stron for the support!

Comment: Note that in general you can remove explicit reference to `DryIoc.dll` since it is a dependency of `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems that there is a registration issue with the implementation type `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleFormatterConfigureOptions` and the service type `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions`.

To find out where this registration is done, you can search for the implementation type `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleFormatterConfigureOptions` in your codebase. Look for any calls to the `Register` method or any other registration methods of the container where this implementation type is being registered.

Once you find the registration, you can check if the service type is correct and update it if necessary. Make sure that the service type `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions` is being registered correctly for the implementation type `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleFormatterConfigureOptions`.